# What is the difference between “to exist” vs “to be real”?

Tags: ontology

What does it mean to say something exists and something is real? And what is the difference if there is any? For example, take a software program. Is it more fitting to say that it exists or that it is real?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Some philosophers distinguish those concepts, but for an answer you'll have to provide some context. Where did you encounter the distinction?

Comment: Sir, please consider the edited question.

Comment: Philosophers who endorse the distinction are usually the ones who advocate a hierarchy of being, different "degrees" of it. On this concept being, or reality, is wider than existence, and there are things (like fictional objects) that do not exist. Software programs, and other abstractions, would have some lower degree of existence than concrete objects, see [What is and how far extends existence?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46352/9148) Alternative view is that all that is real exists, including some abstractions https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-commitment/#QuiCriPre

Comment: In law we have the concept of tangible and intangible property, and it is interesting, and exhausting, to follow the history of the treatment of software here. In philosophy/pedagogy I would draw attention to the Bildung (German). The raw pupil exists, he is not yet real, and the same applies to humanity.  So we might consider Hegel's Phen. of Spirit a Bildungsroman for humanity.

Comment: To exists is to 'stand-out. To be real 'standing out' is not not necessary, Thus for the mystic what exists is not really real and the Real does not stand-out. Iow, every existent can be reduced to the Real. Hence, for instance, F.H. Bradley's essay 'Apearance and Reality' and the distinction he draws. . . .

Comment: Per *dependent arising* that all perceptible and conceivable existences are subtly dependent like the inter-penetrable Indra's net and illusory in the final analysis as [Surangama sutta](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html) described and emphasized: *In the true nature, conditioned things are empty. They spring from causes, as illusions do. Things unconditioned neither rise nor cease. Unreal they are, like flowers in space.* So software only exists as it's dependent on hardware/power and too many other things. The ultimate puzzle is to find the real out of the unreal...

Answer (score 4):

For most purposes, everyday and philosophical, reality and existence, 'real' and 'exists', are interchangeable. There's a distinction of sorts in Meinong. What exists, does so in space/ time. But we might also want to say that numbers, meanings, propositional contents are real but 'subsist'. The common meaning of
propositions - that between 'The dog is red' and 'Le chien est rouge' - the difference could be real but only subsist, not exist in space/ time. It is real in the sense that it can be the subject of true sentences or statements.

To (try to) prevent a tidal wave of criticism let me say that I am aware of the difficulties that beset the putative reality of common meanings, numbers and the rest. But if (IF) they are real, as can be non-absurdly argued, then they do not occupy space/ time and so we have a distinction between the existent and the real.

Answer (score 3):

For most "ordinary" people, and even some philosophers, "to be real" and "to exist" are the same thing.  But not for all philosophers.  Plato (and his followers, the Neoplatonics) famously believed that the things of the ordinary world, which might arguably be said to "exist" were nevertheless not "real" as he defined realness.  Other idealists like Bishop Berekely, might arguably be viewed as having similar views, whether they expressed them in those terms or not.

Even from this point of view, however, it's far from clear if the software program is more or less "real" than other things that "exist."  It has no soul, which argues against it being real in Platonic terms.  It is abstract and conceptual, however, and those are qualities strongly associated with Platonic realness.

Comment: What do you mean by “It has no soul, which argues against it being real in a Platonic sense”? I don’t believe Plato required that things possess a soul to be real. After all, the Forms are the real existents _par excellence_, and while souls are Forms not all Forms are souls — at least not in the sense he discusses in _The Republic_ where he lays out his tripartite theory of the soul. It’s also not common to speak of souls as a modern day platonist. Maybe this was associated with the neo-Platonism of Plotinus and other medieval philosophers?

Answer (score 2):

The distinction is sometimes cast as one between *fundamental* and *derivative* entities. Everything *exists*, but some things might not *really exist*. For example, you might hold that the ultimate constituents of reality are the entities posited by fundamental physics. Everything else is some complex of these things, and is not fundamental.

Although views like this are common, casting it in terms of what “really exists” is less common. The most prominent proponent of such a view is Kit Fine in his “The Question of Realism”. “To be real” would be *to exist in reality*. (Though I don’t believe he holds the strict physicalism described above.)

Answer (score 2):

Great question. This question is best addressed with an answer that "best" separates, differentiates, and clarifies their differences. I use the word "best" because I will be the first to admit the answer I am providing here is not formal, conventional, nor even established. This is my interpretation and I not presenting it for sake of argument. I offer it only as a SINGLE mean of understanding, which is mine.

Let me start with the word 'exist' (a verb used without an object) and its sibling 'existence' (its qualitative state or attribution). The word exist often refers to be or to live, more specifically to CONTINUE to be or to live, as in the phrase "poverty still exists". I believe this convention does not capture the essence of the word because it suggests two misleading and limiting implications. First is the idea that existence in some way refers to an actual entity, living or inanimate. Second that existence is temporal. In other words, existence is equivalent to the actuality of any object, condition, or being and that actuality has a beginning (creation) and an ending (termination). I would like to offer a different dimension of the word, with coordinates not associated with reality and time, but rather, established from the root of the word.

The word 'exist' derives from the Latin words 'ex' meaning out (of) or away (from), and 'sistere' meaning to stand. So its literal origin of meaning was "to stand out" or "stand apart from". Think of a police line up and suspect #3 steping forward. Suspect #3 now appears before you, distinguished from the group of others. The witness can point to him, identify him, describe him. #3 is a particular person in a particular place and time. Are the other suspects real? Of course. But I would propose they don't exist. The others are not definable, distinguishable, or even recognizable because they are not the immediate subject (no pun intended). Let me try another way.

Not long ago I stood before a large photograph of a hummingbird in an art gallery, and what made the photo so captivating is that the background was so blurry all you could make out was some vague, ethereal colors, but the hummingbird, in focus, appeared to pop out from this background. The bird was the subject of the photo. The background most likely consisted of trees, mountains, clouds, a backyard or such. Were the contents of the background real? Certainly, but they didn't exist. The observer could not identify, differentiate, or understand them. For this "standing out" or focus requires an observer. Am I saying entities have an existence only in the regard of an observer? YES. Is this the conventional, proper, or established definition? NO.

Once an observer takes notice of an object, entity, concept, feeling or being, REAL OR IMAGINARY, it now declares its existence. This existence lends way to discovery, inspection, definition, clarification, classification, explanation, comprehension, and most importantly understanding. In fact, ANYTHING (concept, emotion, object, situation, condition, fantasy, being) that can be defined, explained, illustrated, or named exists. If this is confusing, try this. Try to define, explain, illustrate or name anything that DOESN'T exist. Try your best to demonstrate it. It can't be done. If in your retort, a dragon comes to mind, consider this. There is no evidence (yet) that dragons are real. But ask someone to define, describe, or draw one and they could - provided the concept of dragon was presented to them by picture, animation, or story. Show them a picture series of a unicorn, a mermaid, Santa Claus, and a dragon and they will point it out to you. Further, they could likely offer attributes within their description of a dragon (winged, enormous, fire-breathing, green serpent that incinerated dozens of English knights to save Blondie).

Why is this explanation the best? Because it clearly differentiates between entities that exist (subjective presentation) from those that are real (objective actuality). In other words, this distinction clarifies the difference between entities that are merely perceptual from those actual. For instance there are entities in our universe that possess actuality and are objectively real but do not exist to you or me because these entities don't stand out to us. Or here's another way.

I once heard someone state that gravity didn't exist until 1687. It got a laugh out of everyone around, even me. But now I understand AND concur with that statement. Of course the forces of gravity and the laws governing that reality have always been actual, for those forces need no subjective observer to impart effect. Those forces shaped every physical entity in our universe. Gravity is real. But when did the nature and laws of gravity first exist? When they stood out to Newton!

Hope my effort helped or, at very least, gave alternate meaning.

Comment: I made some minor edits which you may roll back or continue editing. You may see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. Although I agree with your answer what would strengthen the answer is to add references to people who think similarly to you. This would give the reader a place to go for more information as well.  Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, there MUST be a difference. It has been argued for *probably* centuries, and it must come to a end.

*Existing Vs. Being Real*

Let us use the analogy: **Illusion**

Illusion, is arguably both true and false. True in a sense that it is and can be presented, therefore exists.. and False, because its nature is referred as fallacious and deceitful.

In an Illusion,
The presence of an object, proves its existence.
But **IF** the accuracy of the object is counterfactual and fabricated, therefore it is false.

Matter and energy are commonly both **TRUE** by existence and **TRUE** by accuracy. 
But information is ALWAYS *(even in emptiness, without space and time)* **TRUE** in existence and **TRUE/FALSE** by accuracy, it really depends on how you translate an information.

**In conclusion**
 There is indeed a difference: Existence: The presence of an object.
——————————-
To be real: The true value of an information, or sometimes, object.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To exist means to have an observable effect on reality. Illusions do have an effect on the behaviour of the illuded person. But they are not real, not part of reality.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed to some ways in which "real" and "exists" can be used differently in philosophy, but there's one that hasn't been mentioned yet--one can be a "realist" about the truth-value of certain propositions, meaning one believes there is some kind of objective mind-independent truth about whether the proposition is true or false, and yet deny that the entities named in the proposition "exist". A good example of this is philosophy of mathematics, the SEP article on mathematical platonism has a [section on truth-value realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/#TruValRea) that makes this distinction:

> Truth-value realism is the view that every well-formed mathematical statement has a unique and objective truth-value that is independent of whether it can be known by us and whether it follows logically from our current mathematical theories. The view also holds that most mathematical statements that are deemed to be true are in fact true. So truth-value realism is clearly a metaphysical view. But unlike platonism it is not an ontological view. For although truth-value realism claims that mathematical statements have unique and objective truth-values, it is not committed to the distinctively platonist idea that these truth-values are to be explained in terms of an ontology of mathematical objects.
>
> Mathematical platonism clearly motivates truth-value realism by providing an account of how mathematical statements get their truth-values. But the former view does not entail the latter unless further premises are added. For even if there are mathematical objects, referential and quantificational indeterminacy may deprive mathematical statements of a unique and objective truth-value. Conversely, truth-value realism does not by itself entail Existence and thus implies neither object realism nor platonism. For there are various accounts of how mathematical statements can come to possess unique and objective truth-values which do not posit a realm of mathematical objects.[2](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#PresEterGrowBlocTheo)

A similar distinction can occur among those who take a realist attitude towards the truth-value of at least some counterfactuals (what-if statements about possible worlds that contradict what happened in our world, like "if [Stanislav Petrov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislav_Petrov) had not disobeyed orders, there would have been a nuclear war in 1983"). The philosopher [David Lewis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/david-lewis/) advocated [modal realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/david-lewis/#6), the notion that other possible worlds exist just like ours, in part because it gave a straightforward answer to how there can be truths about what occurred in other possible worlds. Other philosophers agree there can be truths about other possible worlds, and are in that sense "realists" about such propositions, but they try to find ways to justify that without assuming other possible worlds actually exist. Another example can be found in the philosophy of time, where many [presentists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/) agree with [eternalists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#PresEterGrowBlocTheo) are realists about the past in the sense that they think there are objective truths about what events occurred in past times, but the eternalists think past events and objects exist in exactly the same sense as present ones, while presentists think they have ceased to exist.

One other broad point is that in analytic philosophy, there is a strong tendency to think about metaphysical questions (including the question of whether there are any metaphysical truths at all distinct from scientific or mathematical truths) in terms of a hypothetical exhaustive set of true propositions about reality. For example, in philosophy of mind, those who argue against [eliminative materialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/materialism-eliminative/) often appeal to some notion of [further facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Further_facts) about consciousness that would go beyond a complete set of physical facts, as in [Thomas Nagel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Nagel)'s ["What is it like to be a bat?"](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/cross_fac/iatl/study/ugmodules/humananimalstudies/lectures/32/nagel_bat.pdf) (note his comment on p. 442 that "if the facts of experience—facts about what it is like for the experiencing organism—are accessible only from one point of view, then it is a mystery how the true character of experiences could be revealed in the physical operation of that organism") or [David Chalmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Chalmers)' thought-experiment about a possible [zombie](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zombies/) world where all the physical facts are identical to those in our world, but facts about [qualia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia/) are different.

When it comes to questions of what does and doesn't exist, [Quine's criterion of ontological commitment](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-commitment/#QuiCriPre) has been very influential in analytic philosophy. Basically, the idea here is to imagine a complete set of true propositions about reality expressed in logical language, and then to treat the "nouns" in these propositions (technically, the values of bound variables) as the existing entities, while other terms like the "adjectives" (the [predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)), i.e. properties and relations) are not--one can say something like "the apple is red" and treat the apple as existing but without the need to commit to the color red as a separate existing thing as opposed to a property). However, there are some philosophers who would take the idea of a complete set of true propositions about reality as a primitive notion, and see questions about what terms in these propositions "exist" as meaningless, or purely a matter of human linguistic conventions. In chapter 3 of the book *Metametaphysics: New Essays on the Foundations of Ontology*, David Chalmers refers to this type of position as "ontological anti-realism", writing:

> The basic question of ontology is ‘What exists?’ The basic question of metaontology is: are there objective answers to the basic question of ontology? Here ontological realists say yes, and ontological anti-realists say no.
>
> ...
>
> For example, the ontologist may ask: Do numbers exist? The Platonist says yes, and the nominalist says no. The metaontologist may ask: is there an objective fact of the matter about whether numbers exist? The ontological realist says yes, and the ontological anti-realist says no.
>
> ...
>
> Ontological realism is often traced to Quine (1948), who held that we can determine what exists by seeing which entities are endorsed by our best scientific theory of the world. In recent years, the practice of ontology has often presupposed an ever-stronger ontological realism, and strong versions of ontological realism have received explicit statements by Fine (2000; this volume), Sider (2001; this volume), van Inwagen (1998; this volume), and others.
>
> Ontological anti-realism is often traced to Carnap (1950), who held that there are many different ontological frameworks, holding that different sorts of entities exist, and that while some frameworks may be more useful than others for some purposes, there is no fact of the matter as to which framework is correct. In recent years, versions of ontological anti-realism have been developed by Putnam (1987), Sidelle (2001), Yablo (this volume), and others.
>
> An intermediate sort of *lightweight realism* has also developed, holding that while there are objective answers to ontological questions, these answers are somehow shallow or trivial, perhaps grounded in conceptual truths. Deflationary views of this sort have been developed by Hirsch (1993; this volume), Thomasson (2007; this volume), Hale and Wright (2001; this volume), and others. These views contrast with what we might call the *heavyweight* realism of Fine, Sider, van Inwagen, and others, according to which answers to ontological questions are highly nontrivial.
>
> ...
>
> A consideration favoring deflationary views against heavyweight realism is the following. Say that we know all about the qualitative properties of two objects—two cups, say—and the qualitative relations between them, leaving out any properties or relations concerning objects that they jointly compose. There is a strong intuition that we are thereby in a position to know *everything* relevant there is to know about the objects. There is no deep further truth concerning whether the objects compose a further object (a cupcup, say) of which we are potentially ignorant. The question of whether there is a cupcup is a matter for bookkeeping or for semantic decision, perhaps, but it is not a matter for discovery.

Note that in this last example, the ontological anti-realist is not an anti-realist in general--they may well believe there are objective answers to questions found in physics about the matter/energy making up the cups, like the complete quantum state of all the particles making them up. They just wouldn't believe in any further objective facts about existence, like which subsets of particles constitute existing objects.

Answer (score 0):

The main question seems to me not about discriminating between "to exist" and to "be real". IMO the primordial problem is: Can one **define** the concept of "being real" or the concept of "existing"?

These concepts seem to me so basic or foundational that one cannot reduce their meaning via a definition to other more fundamental concept.

The only way seems to me to take them as **undefined** basic concepts. And to relate them to other fundamental concepts, e.g., to the concepts of "being true" or "being possible".

It could be helpful to study the concepts of "existence" or "being real" in the context of a formal ontology.

Answer (score 0):

What *exists* is a question of what kind of ontology you subscribe to. A theist would say gods or God exists and an athiest would say that gods or God does not exist. So it very much depends.

Ontology isn't a question that is very seriously thought about in certain circles that should think about it a bit harder. For example, Arkani-Hamid (an American-Iranian physicist) says "spacetime is doomed" because certain physicists believe there is a more fundamental atemporal and aspatial substrate. But even if this is true, and I generally go with this, spacetime will still be here. It will still exist. In fact Arkani-Hamid should say, "spacetime as a fundamental ontology is doomed" but that doesn't have the same punchiness of the original - which I guess why Arkani-Hamed favours it.

The question of what is real and what exists is tied up with the history of these two words and what they mean, especially with regards to differing philosophical viewpoints. For example, to take Islamic *Falsafa* (philosophy), they say existence is part of Allah's essence. And He is the most real thing. And everything that exists, exists due to His existence. He is thus the only real thing.

So like I said, it depends. You will need to specify a bit more about the kind of ontology you subscribe to.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the difference between “to exist” vs “to be real”?

The concept of existence is an *epistemological* concept. We say that something exists whenever we perceive or believe that we perceive it.

This is apparent in its etymology: the word "exist" comes from the Latin *existere*, to come forth, be manifest, that is, *ex*- + *sistere*, to stand.

The concept of reality is an *ontological* concept. What is real is real independently of whether *anyone knows that it exists*.

The main consequence of this is that existential claims stem from personal perception or belief, while the question of what things are real literally comes down to common sense, which is produced through verbal interactions and consensus.

This is also why we think of reality as potentially extending beyond (and well beyond) what is manifest. Typically, we learn of the furniture of the real world through our verbal interactions with other people, while our notion of existence starts with ourselves since we have direct knowledge of our own existence.

From the subject's perspective, existence implies reality, but the reality of what one believe exists is decided by public consensus.

Thus, our personal notion of reality starts with our own existence and is gradually extended through experience and perception, and through verbal interactions with other people.

Comment: Is there any basis for your claims besides etymology? Word meanings change, and etymology aside, "existence" has not been traditionally used in philosophy to refer to epistemology--see the [SEP existence on existence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/), which starts by noting that Aristotle used it as synonymous with "essence", while medieval philosophers saw it as dealing with the "being" of a thing distinct from its essence, and later philosophers have had differences with medieval philosophers but still denied any distinction between "existence" and "being" or "instantiation".

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*"existence" has not been traditionally used in philosophy to refer to epistemology*"??? I don't do that either. 2. "*philosophers*" Your résumé shows philosophers disagree among themselves. But the Cogito says, "*I think, therefore I exist*", not "*I think, therefore I am real*". I found my answer on how people actually talk, including philosophers, not on any superficial résumé of 2,600 years of Western philosophy.

Comment: *I don't do that either.* You literally said "Existence is an epistemological concept." Are you interpreting my phrase "refer to epistemology" overly literally? Obviously I didn't mean "philosophers don't treat the word existence as synonymous with the word epistemology", I meant "philosophers don't use existence as an epistemological concept". Descartes' statement can be seen as epistemological, but that doesn't make existence itself an epistemological concept, unless you think a question of the form "how do I know X is true" automatically makes X itself an epistemological concept.

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*overly literally?*" There is such a thing deniability, you know. 2. "*that doesn't make existence itself an epistemological concept*" Of course not. What makes it an epistemological concept is the way that most people use it, whatever philosophers may want to say about it.

Comment: Based on the context that I was responding to your own statement about existence being an epistemological concept, and based on the point that it would just be bizarre to assert that philosophers used the word "existence" completely synonymously with the word "epistemology", I should think it should have been very obvious that literal interpretation of my words wasn't what I meant. As for the other comment, I'd say when "most people" talk about something existing, they are making an objective claim--if they say "X exists" they believe it would exist even if no one *knew* it existed.

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*it should have been very obvious*" And it was. Again, there is such as thing as deniability. 2. "X exists" Sure, to quote myself, "*From the subject's perspective, existence implies reality*".

Comment: OK, so you acknowledge it was "obvious" that I was *not* accusing you of literally saying the word "existence" is identically in meaning to "epistemology"? If you understood I was actually criticizing your claim that existence is an "epistemological concept" why did you say "I don't do that"? And if you agree that a subject (such as a philosopher) sees existence as a question of reality rather than knowledge of reality, doesn't that mean the subject is not using existence as an epistemological concept?

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*you acknowledge it was "obvious"*" Sure, but that I see something as obvious only means that I believe it is true, not that I know it is. 2. "*sees existence as a question of reality*" I don't know what this is supposed to mean so I don't agree with it. 3. "*subject is not using existence as an epistemological concept*" Subjects don't usually understand that they are using concepts, so they don't understand how they are using them. They just use them.

Comment: "I don't know what this is supposed to mean so I don't agree with it." By "sees existence as a question of reality" I mean they see the question of whether or not X exists as having an objective answer which doesn't depend on our knowledge.

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*I mean they see*" I don't believe you understand what all philosophers have said on this. 2. "*whether or not X exists as having an objective answer which doesn't depend on our knowledge*" Sorry, I give up. You are so sloppy with your language, this is hopeless. An objective answer?! What's that?! 3. "*objective*" That people agree that something exists objectively does not imply that it is real. And I'm sure at least some philosophers have understood that.

Comment: At least in analytic philosophy, it is common to define "realism" about a subject in terms of the idea that there are "objective" or "mind-independent" truths about the subject, this isn't my own idiosyncratic terminology. See for example https://iep.utm.edu/nat-kind/#SH3b which says "Scientific realism refers, at a minimum, to the idea that science investigates facts about entities, their properties, and the relations in which they stand that are objective or mind independent."

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*objective or mind-independent*" This does not say anything about the relation between the concepts of existence and reality.

Comment: To say there is an "objective or mind-independent" truth about a given question is just meant as a definition of what it means to be a "realist" about that question, not specifically about questions related to existence. But of course one can believe there is an objective or mind-independent truth about a question like "does X exist?", which shows that existence is not an inherently epistemological (and therefore mind-dependent) notion.

Comment: For example, if you asked a bunch of people if they believe there is a true answer to the question "does alien life exist in this galaxy", one which is independent of human knowledge, don't you think most people would say there is a true answer even if we don't know if it's "yes" or "no"?

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*which shows that existence is not an inherently epistemological (and therefore mind-dependent) notion*" First, no notion is inherently this or that. Second, this does not preclude that existence be an epistemological concept. To again repeat myself, "*From the subject's perspective, existence implies reality*".

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*most people would say there is a true answer*" Sure, so what?

Comment: If a statement that something can be described by some adjective (whether 'existing' or 'red' or 'material') is generally understood as an objective/mind-independent truth, doesn't that imply the adjective does not refer to an "epistemological concept"? If not, what do *you* think would show that some adjective is not an epistemological concept? For any such adjective, like "red" or "material", we can of course ask epistemological questions about how we *know* a thing is accurately described that way, but you aren't saying *all* such adjectives are therefore epistemological concepts, are you?

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*is generally understood as an objective/mind-independent truth*" ??? When is it that you have established that? I only agree that *most people would say there is a true answer*, not that they would agree that the statement "*alien life exists in this galaxy*" is "*an objective/mind-independent truth*". Again, you are being so systematically fluffy in your argument that it seems impossible to have a reasonable conversation.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I suspect that you confusing my claim that existence is an epistemological concept with the very different claim that it is a concept of epistemology.

Comment: Are you saying that in the specific sentence "alien life exists", existence indeed is understood as a mind-independent trait, but then arguing that we can't generalize this to how people usually use the word "exists"? Would you say that in general assertions of the form "X exists" it is *not* usually true that existence is understood as a mind-independent trait?

Comment: As for "fluffy", that is itself a rather fluffy criticism, I'm not sure what specifically you think is bad reasoning/argument here--for example I thought it was reasonable to assume your opinion on existence being mind-independent in the alien life sentence could be generalized, esp. since you didn't specify that you though it was some kind of exception to the rule, and I can't imagine why existence would have a different meaning in a statement like "alien life exists" than in any other typical statement like "trees exist" or "houses exist".

Comment: On your last comment, perhaps you could define what you mean by the phrases "epistemological concept" and "concept of epistemology"? I was assuming that to say "X is an epistemological concept" would mean that the definition of X, or one the core ideas associated with its meaning, would have something to do with epistemological issues like how we get and justify our knowledge-claims.

Answer (score -2):

That is a really good question best one I've heard in a long time. You had me for a minute, but the clear answer is reality is reality based. It's subjective to The Observer. So you define what is real. A cup may exist. But unless you decide it's a cup it is just something sitting on the counter but it still exists. So it's not really a cup until you decide it's a cup.