# The grades of being

Tags: being

I read once that Indian philosophy considers four levels of existence:

- being
- being and not being
- not being and being
- not being

I thought this fascinating and more realistic than Western classifications, even if the text did not specify the exact sense of the Indian concepts. I felt that Western concepts such as 'nothingness' are meaningless : 'nothingness' has no referent and should be avoided in reasoning.

Do you happen to know a little more about the issue?

Comment: I have amended the text, correcting the spelling and more importantly trying to make the question clear. If I have distorted your meaning, or you can make it clearer yourself, you are free to do as you wish with my revision.

Comment: Interesting book about nothing here: https://vdocuments.com.br/altizer-godhead-and-the-nothing.html

Comment: Related [What is and how far extends existence?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/46293/what-is-and-how-far-extends-existence)

Comment: Your question title and body are not quite matching. For this body I feel "modes" may be better than "grades". For some (largely eastern) different gradations see [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/65985/37256)

Answer (score 4):

I expect Samsara and Maya come into the answer to this question, so here is a quote about being and not-being by way of 'being real' and 'not being real':-

*from*  [Wikipedia: The Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_(religion)#The_Upanishads)

> Hendrick Vroom explains, "The term Maya has been translated as
>   'illusion,' but then it does not concern normal illusion. Here
>   'illusion' does not mean that the world is not real and simply a
>   figment of the human imagination. Maya means that the world is not as
>   it seems; the world that one experiences is misleading as far as its
>   true nature is concerned."[35] Lynn Foulston states, "**The world is
>   both real and unreal** because it exists but is 'not what it appears to
>   be'."[6] According to Wendy Doniger, "to say that the universe is an
>   illusion (māyā) is not to say that it is unreal; it is to say,
>   instead, that it is not what it seems to be, that it is something
>   constantly being made. Māyā not only deceives people about the things
>   they think they know; more basically, it limits their knowledge."[36]

Comment: The levels I mentioned do not refer to degree of reality by to the level of existence itself, Just to make a silly but clarifying example, you can think of coma as a possible state of degree 2 or 3.But the meaning of the scale is more profound

Comment: @user157860 How about this type of non-being? https://books.google.gg/books?id=YIPIHWHWRDoC&pg=PA105

Comment: This answer seems spot on to me. For the details I would recommend a study of Nagarjuna.

Answer (score 0):

Grades of Being varies from Religion to Philosophy, from Religion to another Religion or from Tradition to another Tradition.

Some religions or traditions are monotheistic or dualistic or tritheistic or even pluralistic. These religions or traditions mostly look to Matter as Eternal or created by God, non Conscious, since life is created by God, they look also to Godhood as transcendental.

Mostly, in these Religions or Traditions there are Godhood and Metaphysical Conscious Creatures as Angels and Demons, and Physical Creatures as Humans. Thus there are Metaphysical World and Physical World, as we said Godhood is Transcendental, and matter is, mostly, Eternal and Unconscious.

Some religious traditions and philosophies are Pantheistic or Pan-en-theistic.

In Pantheistic, God is the world, namely, matter is in absolute consciousness, thus grades of being in this dogma is:

- World which equals God.
- Atmas or spirits or individual Conscious substances.

In Pan-en-theistic God is both Immanent and Transcendental.